# jQuery: Remove ui-autocomplete styles from dropdown results

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a page that's using jquery's autocomplete and for the life of me I can't remove/modify the styles applied to the dropdown.

I'm using jquery-ui CSS from the google CDN, so i'm trying to avoid saving it locally and modify it  :)

Using CSS, I have tried overriding the UL (.ui-autocomplete), the LI's (.ui-menu-item) and the anchor tags in the LI's - I got a lot of it to work, but there seems to be padding added after my CSS and also, when I move my mouse off a list item onto the next item, for a split second, the previous item has the default jquery-ui background (the grey gradient that is used in headers, such as dialog titlebar).
Anyone have css handy to reset the autocomplete styles?

*** UPDATE ***
Link to fiddle:

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/HccBe/][1]
```

If you hover over one of the items, it highlights in blue. Then move your mouse to the left of it, but still within the dropdown box and you'll notice the blue goes away, but jquery's gradient background sticks around.

Comment: some code sample or jsfiddle would be cool

Comment: it is easier to play with the live example http://jsfiddle.net/L55pE/

Comment: I can't - the site isn't live so the link to get the json wouldn't work =(

Comment: you cant open jsfiddle?

Comment: no I mean the site that would serve the json data, so you can see the problem when you hover over the autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: do you have a problem with styles or data? i added two values `['john', 'jack']` into the autocomplete source. Isn't enought to test the result?

Comment: added jsfiddle :)  - it was my first time every creating a new one; sorry for the delay :)

Comment: OMG! Look carefully at the 3d comment, please. I added jsfiddle yesterday for you http://jsfiddle.net/L55pE/

Comment: dude, i'm so sorry - I totally misread your 3rd comment. I've been multitasking for the last week.  Yep, that's exactly what I need. thanks for your help! I can't accept comments as answers right?  Can you create an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Credit goes to Claustrofob for providing me the CSS to remove all styles off jquery-ui's autocomplete:

```
.ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-active,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-active, 
.ui-autocomplete, .ui-autocomplete:hover, 
.ui-menu-item, .ui-menu-item:hover,
.ui-menu-item a, .ui-menu-item a:hover,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-focus,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-hover,
.ui-widget-header .ui-state-hover,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-focus,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a.ui-state-active,
.ui-menu .ui-menu-item a
{ background: #ffffff none no-repeat; 
padding:0;
margin:0;
display:block;
border:0;border-collapse:collapse;
}
```